# Small device list in Samsung Bada IDE

Tags: javascript, bada, samsung-mobile

I'm trying to write application on the Samsung Bada platform. I'd like to make this application be available on different screen sizes and here are problems with this...

I have to make it work on mobile devices like: Wave 3 GT-8600 (480x800), Wave Y GT-S5380 (320x480) and Wave 578 GT-S5780 (240x400).

As i understood, we have to add device we need to "Device List" into our widget in bada IDE.
In that list we can see different  phone models... I'm looking for Wave-model (in the bottom) so i will choose it, but i'm looking for different screen sizes... and i have no choice.
Maybe i loose something important in bada ide?

Than i visit [bada developers website](http://developer.bada.com/support/faq) and saw there 3 type of files:
HVGA, WQVGA, WVGA - this files are for various screen sizes, right?

i put them to the "bada\2.0.5\Model" folder, but this didn't help me too.. in the device list still no more devices.

does someone know how to add more devices to device list, or how to make to be able to choose screen sizes in that list or.. maybe another way to create one widget for different screen sizes?

Aw, yeah.. my problem is: height and width of widget on different screen sizes.
This properties we can set in project.xml file in the root folder of widget. At this moment i have the same properties of widget for all screen sizes (from 240x400 to 480x800).
I set 220width x 130height for widget, and everything fine at small screen (240x400) and middle (320x480) screen, but in the large screen (480x800) widget can be get out off the screen if you move it at the right angle.
Also we can not set sizes of WIDGET larger than SCREEN size, because after installing widget will automatically became application (some bada magic), when i need only widget.

That's why i'm looking for possibility to set different "project.xml" files for different screen sizes.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're targeting bada 2.0, you can do a resolution independent app, where the right resource files are pickup up automatically by the system based on the current phone's specs. You'd get an abstracted display surface that's always 480 *logical* pixels wide, scaling to physical pixels is done internally.

And for development purposes, there are only three bada device types out there - WQVGA (240x320), HVGA (320x480), WVGA (480x800). Those are resolutions, not screen sizes. Screen size is roughly in the same ballpark, about 4".

Comment: yes, bada 2.0  
but in my case i have to make 3 files of project.xml, because widget width and height set exactly there, and as i know we can not dinamically change something in this files or dinamically load them.. they are inited first of all

Comment: Widgets... Unknown territory for me :)

Comment: maybe you know someone who develop bada widgets?)